# C++ code Error - no operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++

The below C++ code in Visual Studio 2017 does not get compiled, instead it throws this exception:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    vector<int> a[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << "\nHello world";
}
```

Error Message shown is as follows:

```
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands
 operand types are: std::ostream << std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>
Error (active)  E0349   no operator ">>" matches these operands
operand types are: std::istream >> std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>
```

I wonder what is the Issue. Any Suggestions would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: I think you simply forgot to `#include <iostream>`!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, Could you please check the edited version.

Comment: You're probably not supposed to use an array of vectors there, but just `vector<int> a(5);` to get a vector with five preallocated elements. @Peter is on a completely wrong track in their comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, the OP *didn't* have iostream included in their first version...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica TBH, I didn't ever see that version, it was corrected by the OP after your comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually, it would be nice to not rely on constant sizes and build the vector dynamically, for robustness and maintainability. The naive way to do that would be to introduce a temporary variable, read into that, and then `push_back()` it into the vector. But that's clumsy. Can one do some iterator or algorithm magic treating `cin` as a sequence that's then copied into the vector? Can you sketch an example?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know. The error wasn't fitting for that reason, I should have paid better attention (cin/cout would have been unknown as well.) But if you have an elegant copy cin -> vec solution I'd be curious!

Comment: @Peter I am not quite sure what you mean? Something like a `vector_builder` class with an overloaded indexing operator, thus you could write `vector_builder<int> b; std::vector<int> a = b[5];`? I don't see any advantage in doing such?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See my edited answer: std::copy with iterators. Advantages are debatable ;-).

Answer (score 1):

`vector<int> a[5];` defines an array of 5 vectors; consequently, `a[i]` is an entire vector. Use round brackets, making the 5 a size argument to the vector constructor: define the vector as `vector<int> a(5);` instead.

Of course, having a constant size is error-prone and hard to maintain. Vectors are there exactly to prevent this kind of inflexibility. The typical way vectors are used is to build them up dynamically. They keep track of their size internally. Adding an element is not as easy as with maps though: Simply saying <strike>`a[27] = 3;`</strike> will not create element 28 (and the ones inbetween). It could, of course; but the interface was not designed that way. Instead, we have the [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) way to append an element by copying, or [`emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to append an element by constructing it *in situ* (which saves a copy). Using `push_back`, a valid version would be

```
vector<int> a;
while(cin)
{ 
   int newVal;
   cin >> newVal;
   if(cin) { a.push_back(newVal); } // add to vector if input was good
}
```

This detects the end of input by checking the health of `cin` via its convenient bool conversion. That works fine for use cases like `echo "1 2 3 4 5" | myProg`. For manual terminal input the user must perform a a special action to indicate end of input, like pressing ctrl-d in a *nx terminal or ctrl-z in a Windows console. Newline, by contrast, is treated like all other whitespace.

What I didn't like here was the temporary variable; it's really not needed. The approach seemed a bit pedestrian. If nothing else it's very 90s, and you cannot impress anybody with it. The reviewer will look at it and see it is correct without looking anything up or having any questions. Let's make their life just a bit harder by being more modern and more abstract.

Considering that both the input stream and the vector are *sequences of objects* that can be iterated I wondered whether one can simply use a standard library facility that copies one sequence to another, without regards for the specific types behind the sequences. And indeed, there is an iterator for vector that back-inserts when you assign to it, aptly named [`back_inserter`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/). So we can use the std::copy algorithm. Here is a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::back_inserter
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy

using namespace std; // less clutter

int main ()
{
  vector<int> vec; // size is 0, cannot access any vec[i].

  // The input routine, a bit abstract.
  std::copy (   istream_iterator<int>(cin), // source start
                istream_iterator<int>(),    // source end
                back_inserter(vec)          // destination
            );

  cout << "vec contains: ";
  for ( auto it = vec.begin(); it!= vec.end(); ++it )
  {
      cout << ' ' << *it;
  }
  cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Is this better or worse? A question for code review. Experience tells me that keeping code as obvious and simple as possible without too much redundancy  has a lot of merits. But for modern C++ the abstract solution is, I think, pretty idiomatic: Away from concrete types and specific data shuffling towards targeting commonalities and algorithms.

Of course, the output is now standing out as oldschool as well. We could write

```
  std::copy (   vec.begin(),
                vec.end(),
                ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")
            );
```

The second argument to the ostream_iterator is a string that is appended after each output, including the last one; that is a common but stupid problem, and a general example that abstraction often means to compromise at the detail level (e.g., if you have ever wondered why certain property dialogs e.g. in VS are so shitty: I bet they are generated, not manually programmed). To gloss over it, I omitted the commas between numbers; a simple space will do, and the trailing space is invisible, as opposed to a trailing comma. But I think the scale here tips towards oldschool.